# A good place to start learning Behaviorism for a Newbie?

Tags: reference-request, behaviorism

I've developed an interest in Behavioral Psychology. I don't have any background and I'm not taking any Psychology course or anything. I just want to learn. I was wondering if there's a good "Beginners" book on this topic, or a good place to start. Googling returned varied results, which confused me.

**Summing up what I'm looking for:**

- An ordered series of Book titles (ordered by beginner level to expert level)
- A website/blog/forum to follow

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be better to follow a series of instructional courses provided on the internet. MIT in their Opencourseware has provided an [Introduction to Psychology](https://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/introduction-to-psychology/id341596834?mt=10) class lectures through iTunesU. They also provide a structured study guide for the rest of their [Psychology courses](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/find-by-topic/#cat=socialscience&subcat=psychology) (some have videos). Each course has a syllabus and assigned book reading.

Answer (score 4):

A great open lecture set is Human Behavioral Biology by Robert Sopolsky through Stanford. It's on YouTube.  I also recommend Paul Bloom's Intro to Psych through Yale open courses.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. It's a shame I couldn't accept both yours and @caseyr547's answers.

Answer (score 0):

Karen Pryor's book *Don't Shoot the Dog* is an ideal introduction to Behaviorism for the layman.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why it's good?